# Limit the has_many output when using as_json to include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, limit

In our app we have models that are connected with each other.
For my example I will use Client and Person.

One Person can have many Clients, one Client can have many people.

We use the following pattern to return the data trough the API

```rb
Person.first.as_json(include: { clients: { only: ['id', 'name'] } })
```

In some cases there are a lot of connections between a Person and Clients. In our overview query, we wouldn't want to show all the information about all Clients, just the first 3 and on click on "more" we'd load the rest.

How can I achieve this, hopefully with minimal changes to this pattern?
I tried googling and checking other similar responses, but they were either plain not working or there was some hard coding involved, which is not optimal, but in a pinch, i'd be happy with even that.

I tried adding a `limit` to the `as_json` which is just being ignored.

I tried adding a class method to change the output and append the `clients` but that ended up editing the models too.

I tried working my way up from using SQL to creating a query, but that does not work as expectedd.

Comment: ActiveRecord doesn't actually have a good built in way to "cap" an assocation - when preload, eager_load, etc are used you can't just add a limit to the query as that limits the entire query. Instead you need to do workarounds to get the X number of records, assign it and mark the association as loaded.  https://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/

Comment: @max Thanks for the reply; I will checkout the gem that you wrote about in your blog post; I might also have an Idea how to implement this more "by hand" but still looking to find some good pointers.

Comment: Unfortunatly it's a harder problem then it seems. The way LIMIT works in SQL is that it applies to the entire query instead of for example getting N number of rows per group. Instead you have to use techniques like doing a window query or lateral join to get the ids of the newest records. Whatever solution you come up with is going to be fairly RDBMS specific.